# Capybara - spec with `within_window` does not work without `sleep`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a spec that clicks a button, which triggers some JS generating url and opens it in a new window:

```
new_window = window_opened_by { find('#search_postcode').click }
within_window new_window do
  expect(page.current_url).to include('postcode.nl')
end
```

This does not work. I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(page.current_url).to include('postcode.nl')
       expected "about:blank" to include "postcode.nl"
```

However, when I add `sleep 1`, the spec passes:

```
within_window new_window do
  sleep 1
  expect(page.current_url).to include('postcode.nl')
end
```

Is it possible to get this working without the `sleep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for a selector within the new windows html. Capybara then should wait the default_waittime for the element to appear. Like:

```
within_window new_window do
  expect(page).to have_selector('.your_class_here')
  expect(page.current_url).to include('postcode.nl')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without needing to test for an elements presence you can use the provided `have_current_path` matcher which includes waiting/retrying behavior and should generally (99.9% of the time) be preferred over using an RSpec provided text matcher with the result of `current_url`

```
within_window new_window do
  expect(page).to have_current_path(/postcode\.nl/, url: true)
end
```